# Store an NSArray globally to save data bandwidth from downloading content

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-management

I am making an application which as a part of it needs to download information from 2 RSS feeds.

However these feeds will have that information used across the entire app and may or may not be reloaded as the user requires to see their selected `UIViewController`.

So my question is:

Is it advisable to setup these arrays on application load in the `UIAppDelegate` or is that a big no-no in regards to performance?

I have the code working, I am just wanting to know what the best place would be to execute it to minimize data usage and also at the same time be best accessible throughout the app?

Any help would be great, because there is a lot of code to shift around if I need to keep re-doing this.
Thanks for the advice.

PS I know there is a lot of reading I can do and am doing, using SO is part of this research  to get developers opinions. I hope that it does not break any rules or upset people :-)

Comment: If you want to access it always and from every single class - go for singleton - much cleaner solution and accessing it - instead of always searching for UIAppDelegate.

Comment: And can singletons be as big as I need them to be? To load an RSS feed into an Array is a bit of code.

Comment: Sure - if you really have a lot of code you can uncapsulate your code into a class which will be created and connect to singleton.

Comment: ok - that would be worth looking into. do you know any good example's or happen to know a tutorial on that? I have seen tutorials on Singletons, but find it hard to translate it into my head since explanations are not always well written.

Comment: This link would help http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/ and I have used in a real situation to test for reachability using a singleton using this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-detecting-network-changes-with-reachability/

Comment: Thanks for the links - will study them today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a File as an NSObject, do header like this;

```
@interface myData : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *myDataArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myDataArray;

+ (myData *)sharedData;

@end
```

Then in the .m add this

```
#import “myData.h”

static myData *sharedData;

@implementation myData

@synthesize myDataArray;

+ (myData *)sharedData
{

    if(!sharedData)
    {
        sharedData = [[myData alloc] init];
    }
    return sharedData;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        myDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in each of your VCs, simply #import "myData.h" and when you need it do this;

```
myData *localShared = [myData sharedData];

localShared.myDataArray = // This is your array and will look the same throughout
NSString *myStringObj = localShared.myDataArray[4];  // So you can do this kind of stuff
```

This from memory, I have not tested but I think this is very close.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Cool thanks for this simplicity - will work on it today.

Comment: It worked fine :-) and I get it know :-) I just need to figure out how to transfer the data to another ViewController, because even I can generate it (check with NSLog) the data is generated in another method.

Comment: All you need is the last part in each Method on any VC that you want to use it.  I would not bother copying it to array in the local VC and back again, one line (myData *localShare = [myData sharedData];) will create localShare which you can use in that Method, just repeat for another method.

Comment: Cool - I will try that, I did settle for copy at this stage, was happy that it worked :-)